# Is there any free iOS SDK for syling maps?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, dictionary

I'm searching a free SDK for coloring maps (Not markers, but entire map).
I found Mapbox and ArcGIS, but I want to know if there's a free alternative with Google Maps integration.

Or this is posible with a native library, I read that this is not possible right now?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to overlay the provided baseman, or provide your own custom baseman?

Comment: Hi, i need to just overlay the provided baseman, just adding colors to the land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can likely use `MapKit`.  Check out the documentation for [MKOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html), which allows you to create views that draw over the top of the basemap.  You can draw lines, areas, whatever you want.